# v1.0 - commonName in a legalName to create node

Tags: corda

If I uses a commonName in a legalName to create a node (at least for MockNetwork), then networkMapCache.getNodeByLegalName(legalName) returns null.  After removing the commonName, it works.  Is that by design?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Corda V1.0. When creating a node, the `common name` part of the name is nulled out. However, when looking up a node using the network map, the `common name` field is not nulled out, so no match is found.

The Corda team will backport a fix to Corda V1.0 to throw an exception when a regular node is created with a common name. In Corda V1.0, a common name is used solely by notary clusters to identify one another.

In a future version of Corda, the Corda team will examine re-enabling the `common name` field for regular nodes.